# Specman e: All files start with the word "package" - what does it mean?

Tags: package, specman

in my verification environment all e files starts with the word "package", i.e.:

```
<'
    package spi;
.
.
.
'>
```

Do you know what does it mean?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`package` is an encapsulation concept in `e`. It is similar to a `namespace` in `C++`. This means that, for example a struct called `foo` inside one package is totally different from a struct called `foo` inside a different package.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to creating namespaces (that avoid name clashes), it also allows to use access control on types and struct members.
A type, a field, a method, or an event can be declared as *package-private*, for example:

```
package type color: [RED, GREEN];

struct packet {
    package foo() is { ... };
};
```

A type or a struct member declared with the `package` access modifier, can only be accessed from within the same package. By the way, for struct members there are also `private` and `protected` access modifiers. `protected` means that the field or the method cannot be accessed from within a different struct, and `private` just means both `package` and `protected`. (Notice that the meaning of these access modifiers is different than in C++ or in Java; for example, in C++ the difference between `protected` and `private` is whether the member can be accessed from within the same exact class, or from within the class and its subclasses).